# Generic static methods within a generic class

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have:

```
public class Parent<T extends Child1>  {
    public Parent() {       
    }

    public static <T extends Number> void test(T t) {
    }
}
```

And `Child1` is a child class of `Parent`.

What I'm trying to understand here is the connection between the parameter type `T` in both class scope and method scope. How can both parameters (class' and method's) be allowed to be named `T` if their bounds are completely different from one another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type parameter defined in the method is completely independent of the one defined in the class. In fact, you've to define type parameter for static methods, as class-level type parameters can't be used there. You can't use class-level type parameter in static context. That's outside their scope. So, if you remove that method level type parameter declaration, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: This just summed it up for me!

Comment: One last thing. Does the same apply for non-static methods, or is defining a generic parameter on a method always exclusive to that method, regardless of their visibility?

Comment: @Dimitri Yes, defining a type parameter on any method is independent of the one defined in class.